# Loading markup to show only once, on first page visit

Tags: jquery, html, loading

I have a loading markup that covers the whole window waiting on document.ready() function to fire. Then my loading markup fades and the real content appears.

My issue is that while I am still navigating on the site if I hit Home again the loading markup appears, even if it is for a very short moment, as the code is executed again.

I don't want to wait again once all images are in the temp, I would like to go straight to the Home page and keep the loading div display:none.

How can I execute the loading page only once on the Home page at every fresh visit of the site?

Comment: Try to have cookie value set for few hours and check for that cookie. If it is not there show loader else don't show it.

Comment: post some code....That is where you have coded up all the loading stuff.

Comment: @NagaHarishMovva I tried with the cookies, but I probably do something wrong:    $(function () {
 if (!isset($_COOKIE["once"])) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#topBackground").hide();
  });
  $(window).load(function(){
   $("#loading").fadeOut("slow");
   $("#topBackground").fadeIn("slow");
  });
 } else {
  $("#topBackground").show();
  $("#loading").hide();
  setcookie("once", "1", time()+600, "/");
 }
});

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code sample.. Please use this to implement your needs. In this sample code I set cookie expiry time for 8 hours `cookieExpiry.setTime(cookieExpiry.getTime() + (8 * 3600 * 1000));`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #WelcomeDiv, #SecondTimeDiv {
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="WelcomeDiv">This div will visible only first time with in 8 hours</div>
    <div id="SecondTimeDiv">This div will show with in that 8 hours..</div>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            if (document.cookie.indexOf("visited") >= 0) {
                //Don't open any pop up here... You can do something here
                alert("Pop up already shown");
                $("#SecondTimeDiv").show();
            }
            else {
                // set a new cookie..
                var cookieExpiry = new Date();
                cookieExpiry.setTime(cookieExpiry.getTime() + (8 * 3600 * 1000)); // 8 hours
                document.cookie = "visited=yes; expires=" + cookieExpiry.toGMTString();
                alert("Show pop up here");//Do here something...
                $("#WelcomeDiv").show();
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this will helpful for your needs.. Please check in all browsers.. I test only in Firefox..

Comment: Thank you it was very helpful and sorry for the late reply. I changed project and just came back to it.